# WordPress. Сломалась пагинация. Не делит на страницы

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Доброго времени суток!
Проблема заключается в том, что WP не высчитывает количество страниц. Стоят два плагина WP-PageNavi (активен), WP-Paginate (отключен).
В итоге, на странице 419 записей, и все они на первой странице. Внизу отображается, что это первая страница, и всё. Больше страниц нет. В настройках менял количество записей на странице и по 10, и по 20, не помогает.
Несколько дней мучаюсь с проблемой, уже не знаю где копать.

Comment: Идиома "биться об заклад" означает "серьезно спорить, на деньги".

Comment: @KAGG Design Спасибо, я учту на будущее. Что поделаешь, не филолог.

Comment: В functions.php